# How to stop my texts (iMessage) from showing on my Mac

Tags: macos, messages, iphone

Whenever I send or receive messages on my iPhone they show up on my MacBook also. I was wondering how I could get that to stop?

It used to be that my texts wouldn't show up, and I could message through my MacBook also but now its just annoying and I'd rather not have my siblings creeping through my messages by reading them on my laptop.

Comment: You can temporarily disable notifications by opening the notification centre and enabling "do not disturb".

Answer (score 2):

Disable it in iMessages Prefs/Accounts...

[Edit] Re-reading your question, you want to be able to send from iPhone & MacBook, but not have the MacBook show any conversations initiated from the phone?
Never tried that one, but perhaps by disabling one or more of the account number/email address options further down the same page.

I've always had conversations appear in both locations, Mac & phone, never seen it behave any differently, unless I was in some poor reception area.

[image: Imessage Prefs/accounts pic]

Answer (score -2):

Go to System Preferences → Accounts and unclick on the iMessaging Service.
It will say it is "inactive".

This is for OS X 10.10.