# How do I disable iMessage on every computer I installed with my email address?

Tags: messages

I have two multiple Macs. 2 Macbooks and an iMac. I installed El Capitan on all of them, with my one iTunes account.

The issue I am running into is that whenever I get a message on iMessage, it shows up on all computers and my iPad...not just my iPhone (and my Macbook) -- which is what I want.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I don't believe there's any way to do a broad-sweep method, [you can disable it on a case-by-case basis](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146113/how-to-stop-my-texts-imessage-from-showing-on-my-mac) on OS X and iOS.

**OS X**

Open the Messages app, then in the menu bar hit Messages -> Preferences. Click on the Accounts button, then your iMessage account in the sidebar. Uncheck the box labeled "Enable this account."

[image]

**iOS**

[Go to Settings -> Messages and turn iMessage off.](https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage)

[image]

Comment: Perfect. This is just what I was looking for. Thanks much!

Comment: @marcamillion Glad to hear it :)